# How to instantiate a class just by having the class object and cast the result just by using the class from which it was instantiated?

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following problem: 
I have a class object(MyClass.class) and from that class object i need to instantiate an object.That is the easy part ois `MyClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` (the class has only one constructor which takes no arguments).

The tricky part(or so i think) is to cast the resulted object to the appropriate type(MyClass) using the class object with which i created.
Note that i can't write the following code `(MyClass)MyClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

If someone can help me with this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Casting is about the compile-time type.  If all you have is a `Class` object, you have no compile-time type.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: public void function(Class c){  (how do i cast this?)c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();                                                                        }

Comment: You can't, and it wouldn't mean anything anyway.

Comment: Calling `newInstance()` on a class object sort of implies that you know what the type is when you instantiate it, or else you wouldn't have called it. In most use cases, there's someone writing code up the chain that knows at compile time what the type of the reflected class is, and would cast a returned object explicitly. Your `void` function should probably return the object instead of doing something with it in the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:

```
MyClass.class.cast(myInstance);
```

[See also the relevant Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-). Not that this would be very useful apart from null-checking and type-checking:

```
public T cast(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && !isInstance(obj))
        throw new ClassCastException(cannotCastMsg(obj));
    return (T) obj;
}
```

... but this is how you cast a class using reflection, and I suspect that this question is about some test or assignment anyway

Comment: The problem was that i was calling getDeclaredConstructors() and from there calling newInstance() gave me an Object, but anyway your answers were what i needed.Thanks!

Comment: @Carolik: Aha, but you're aware that you can call the default constructor simply via `Class.newInstance()`, if it is public?

Comment: If it is public - yes, but if not...i must make accesible and that leads to my first case, the one that i wanted to avoid and because of your answers i can now gladly avoid it:)